# Aggregation while using count(distinct)

Tags: sql

I have a table with 50 columns named as public_report. I want count(distinct) of a specific column along with all the columns as I need to run this in Tableau

```
select count(distinct l.lead_key), l.*
from public_report l
group by l.lead_key
```

I am facing this error while i execute a query for

> Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42803]
>   ERROR: column "l.enquiry_key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

II tried adding l.enquiry_key but it threw a other column name as well. have around 50 columns can anyone suggest.

Also tried this

```
select t.lk, t.c, lp.*
from (select lead_key lk, count(distinct lead_key) c
      from public_report
      group by lead_key) t
join public_report lp 
    on lp.lead_key = t.lk
```

but this is not giving me the correct count.

This table has 8700000 distinct lead_key values. But I am getting 14565498 as count d value

Please help

Comment: share sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a correlated subquery is what you want?

```
select p.*, (select count(*) from public_report p2
             where p2.lead_key = p.lead_key)
from public_report p
```

Comment: This is not giving the correct result. Also I want the distinct count of lead key along with all other columns

Answer (score 0):

If youwantknow the number of distinct lead_key You should not group by for the same row you want aggregated

```
select count(distinct l.lead_key)
from public_report l
```

if you want the count for each key then use group by ket and count(*)

```
select l.lead_key,  count(*)
from public_report l
group by l.lead_key
```

if you want count(distinct l.lead_key)  aside the others column you could use a cross join

```
   select lp.*, t. my_count 
   from  public_report lp 
   cross join  (
      select count(distinct l.lead_key) my_count
      from public_report l
   ) t
```

if you want the count of each lead_key aside the the others columns  you could use  an inner join with subwuery with group by

```
   select lp.*, t.my_lk_count 
   from  public_report lp 
   inner  join  (
        select l.lead_key,  count(*) my_lk_count
        from public_report l
        group by l.lead_key
   ) t  ON t.lead_key = lp.lead_key
```

Comment: I want the distinct count of lead key along with all other columns so instead of lead_key i used other column name  and below is the error                                                                                        
 Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42803] ERROR: column "l.enquiry_key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select lp.*, t.count_distinct
from public_report lp cross join
     (select count(distinct lead_key) as count_distinct
      from public_report
     ) t;
```

Or, because most databases support `count(distinct)` as a window function:

```
select pr.*, count(distinct lead_key) over () as count_distinct
from public_report pr
```

Comment: not working tried select lp.*, t.count_distinct
from public_report lp cross join
     (select count(distinct lead_key) as count_distinct
      from public_report
     ) t;

Comment: I am not getting correct value of count distinct function